# Active Directory authorization: IIS vs Visual Studio Dev server

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-authentication, vs-devserver

I have a web project that uses Active Directory authorization (All controllers marked with `AuthorizeAttribute`). In web.config i have following authentification section:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

The problem is: 
When i run project under Visual Studio Development Server everything goes fine, it pops authorization window, after entering login/password i can see all site contents.

But, when i try to run it under IIS (7.5) authorization window still pops, but login/password is always incorrect (looks like it cannot access AD).
Site is configured to use windows authorization. Application pool runs using my windows login/password. What am i missing?

Comment: Are you using impersonation in your application?

Comment: Are you running IIS on the same machine, or on a server somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your host header file is pointing to 127.0.0.1, it may be the authentication loopback check.

If that is the case, the answer is already detailed at [why does windows authentication / impersonation fail on asp.net application with iis 7.5 / windows 7 /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015434/why-does-windows-authentication-impersonation-fail-on-asp-net-application-with?rq=1). In short, open regedit, and add a DWORD DisableLoopbackCheck = 1 to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem, following solved my problem:

1. Select website
2. Select "**Features View**".
3. Open "**Authentication**" section.
   Note: I am Assuming your website has Windows Authentication enabled as stated above by you.
4. Select "**Windows Authentication**"
5. In right side "**Actions**" section, click on providers.
6. Now from "**Providers**" Pop-up select "**Negotiate**" and **remove** it.
7. refresh website & run

Please let me know if it works for you.